# Java Drools Engine 8.29 is not loading excel file

Tags: java, drools

Im using Drool decision table and loading an excel(.xls) file. Right not it is not loading the excel sheet and also there are no errors to logs that says it did not load it.

Can anyone help me with this issue please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...decision table and loading an excel(.xls) file...

Likely, your *excel(.xls) file* does NOT have a file name ending with `.drl.xls`, `.drl.xlsx`, or `.drl.csv`.

That is why is not picked up.

[image: documentation highlight]

Ref [https://docs.drools.org/8.36.0.Final/drools-docs/docs-website/drools/language-reference/index.html#decision-tables-defining-proc:~:text=Starting%20with%20Drools%20v8%2C%20file%20extension%20must%20end%20in%20either%20.drl.xls%2C%20.drl.xlsx%2C%20or%20.drl.csv%20as%20mentioned%20in%20the%20Release%20Notes](https://docs.drools.org/8.36.0.Final/drools-docs/docs-website/drools/language-reference/index.html#decision-tables-defining-proc:%7E:text=Starting%20with%20Drools%20v8%2C%20file%20extension%20must%20end%20in%20either%20.drl.xls%2C%20.drl.xlsx%2C%20or%20.drl.csv%20as%20mentioned%20in%20the%20Release%20Notes).

Comment: Good guess. Probably a better link: https://docs.drools.org/8.36.0.Final/drools-docs/docs-website/drools/language-reference/index.html#decision-tables-defining-proc . I do note that the 8.29 docs (which is the version in the OP) doesn't actually have this tip ...

Comment: Hi @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas yes  we introduced this tip in multiple places in the doc since we reckon it was done for Kogito, but was not yet documented for Drools v8 :)